# How to exclude files by part of directory path

Tags: powershell

I am grabbing all files from a folder recursively.

I want to exclude some directories.

This example works fine, but it only deals with the file extensions

```
$excluded = @("*.png", "*.svg", "*.jpg")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -File -Exclude $excluded
```

One of the paths could contain the directory `/debug/`, which I don't want to include. However the following has no effect

```
$excluded = @("*\bin\*", "*\obj\*")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -File -Exclude $excluded
```

I am still getting results such as `c:\myProj\folder\bin\`

I then tried (showing full code)

```
$excluded = @("*.png", "*.svg", "*.jpg", "*.csproj", "*.sln","*.config","*.dep", "*.gif", "*.license", "*.dll", "*.nupkg", "*.exe", "*.application","*.manifest","*.xml","*.pdb", "*.cache")
$excludedPath = @("*\bin\*", "*\obj\*","*\System.Test\*")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -File -Exclude $excluded | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike $excludedPath}
```

Same issue!

PowerShell 5.1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[James C.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746501/45375) offers an elegant solution that uses *regex*-matching rather than wildcards to match the path portion.

As for:

> What am I doing wrong?

- **`-Exclude` and `-Include`** only ever **operate on the *last* path component**; i.e., the file or directory *name* of the input file at hand.
- The **`-like`** operator only supports ***one* pattern on the RHS** (you can, however, use an array of *input strings* on the LHS to compare to that one pattern)

  - By passing it an *array* as the RHS, PowerShell implicitly converts it to a *string* with the array elements concatenated with spaces, resulting in a pattern that doesn't match anything; 
    specifically, the resulting pattern is `*\bin\* *\obj\* *\System.Test\*`

---

James C.'s regex-based answer is simpler, but if you did want to use **multiple wildcard patterns** to match the paths also, the simplest approach would be to use the **`switch` statement with the `-Wildcard` option**:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -File -Exclude $excluded |
  Where-Object {
    switch -Wildcard $_.FullName {
      *\bin\*         { return $False }
      *\obj\*         { return $False }
      *\System.Test\* { return $False }
      default         { return $True }
    }
  }
```

---

On a side note: Enhancing `-Include` \ `-Exclude` to optionally work against *full paths* is being proposed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126).

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude folders with regex matching as it saves all the wildcards, in this case `|` is an 'or' match.

Then use `-notmatch` to exclude anything that matches the exclusions.

`FullName` includes the file name, so I'm using `DirectoryName` so that it doesn't exclude files that match.

```
$excluded = @("*.txt", "*.csv")
$excludedPath = 'bin|obj|System.Test'

Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -File -Exclude $excluded |
  Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -notmatch $excludedPath}
```